# Autofac configuring NHibernate ISession to allow null

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, dependency-injection, fluent-nhibernate

I am still new to dependency injection, and it seems like I'm missing something.

I used Autofac as my container to resolve every repositories dependency to NHibernate session.

The session receive a dependency of SystemSetting, which pretty much only consisted of MySql connection string.

At the beginning of application I configure all registered dependency, including the initialization of SessionFactory.

The case is, if the connection string is wrong, the application throws a compile time exception that it cannot connect to MySql with provided connection string. What if I wanted to allow this misconfiguration so the user can then set own his own the correct, let's say, ip address?

My problem is, I cannot get the application to the Login Form, since Login Form received User Repository as a dependency which in turn receive an, supposedly, active session, therefor throwing an exception.

Should I exclude the creation of NHibernate session out of Autofac configuration?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you'd be better off when injecting singleton lifetime-scoped `ISessionFactory` instead of `ISession`. And you can disable the reserved keywords check on session factory creation so the application doesn't crash.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Singleton lifetime scoped ISessionFactory means every repository will receive ISessionFactory for their dependency and then created an ISession afterward. Is that how? And I can't grasp anything about reserved keywords thing. Please elaborate more, sorry for troubling you.

Comment: It means that there's *one* instance of `ISessionFactory` injected to each component, and each of those components creates its own `ISession` (or multiple `ISessions` if needed). As for the keywords check, by default NHibernate connects briefly to the database when building the `ISessionFactory` to check for reserved keywords (that's for schema/DDL creation). You can disable that, so the first connection to the database will be made on the first `ISession` use.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer, because it works. One more thing, your method seems fine, but now I can't test my connection with another connection string to make sure NHibernate can connect to MySql because it no longer throws any exception. And I checked the returned Session object's IsConnected property strangely set as true. Do you know a way to test this?

Comment: Added. I'm not quite sure how you want to test your connection, separate connection string means you'd have to create a different `ISessionFactory`, but maybe there's something I'm missing here. Also the sessions created by `OpenSession` are, well, open by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you'd be better off when injecting singleton lifetime-scoped `ISessionFactory` instead of `ISession`.

It means that there's one instance of `ISessionFactory` injected to each component, and each of those components creates its own ISession (or multiple `ISessions` if needed).

As for the keywords check, by default NHibernate connects briefly to the database when building the `ISessionFactory` to check for reserved keywords (that's for schema/DDL creation). You can disable that, so the first connection to the database will be made on the first `ISession` use.